# What is the best practical way to decrease react native app launch time?

Tags: react-native, launch-time

I have read so many articles but still couldn't get a proper solution on possible ways to reduce app launch time for react native app.

On Analysing my app loads 1243 modules and 1770 modules are in waiting state for the first time the app is loaded. It is taking 12 seconds for the app to load and display splash screen.

I want to reduce this 12 seconds time to at least 6-9 seconds.

Comment: tried this ? simplify your splash screen AND
move some initial logic to the native side. more about this in [HERE](https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/measuring-and-improving-react-native-apps-startup-time).

Answer (score 1):

This one is a good article to [Improve Start-up Time](https://www.crowdbotics.com/blog/how-to-get-better-performance-out-of-your-react-native-app)
If you aren't already gone through it.